# Imported map resizes and flickers in RViz

Tags: navigation, rviz, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I run Ridgeback robot on RVIZ with nagivation stack. Everything worked fine, I have the robot model in RVIZ  and I was able to navigate around and created a map. The problem happened when I tried to use the existing map, the model will keep flickering and the map only show up when i click on reset in RVIZ. Here are the commands and steps that I use to bring out the existing map to RVIZ:

- Because my navigation stack stored inside the robot, I run these launch files in robot terminal seperately:

In Terminal 1:

```
source devel/setup.bash
roslaunch ridgeback_navigation odom_navigation_demo.launch
```

In Terminal 2:

```
source devel/setup.bash
roslaunch jackal_navigation gmapping.launch
```

In Terminal 3:

```
source devel/setup.bash
roslaunch ridgeback_viz view_robot.launch config:=gmapping
```

In Terminal 4:

```
roslaunch ridgeback_navigation amcl_demo.launch map_file:=/home/administrator/ridgeback_world.yaml
```

After that in my laptop terminal.

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://cpr-r100-0019:11311
export ROS_IP=192.168.0.103
export ROS_HOSTNAME=laura-Precision-M6400/
roslaunch ridgeback_viz view_robot.launch config:=local
```

*Note that I saved my map files inside the robot, because when i saved it in the laptop, the file won't launch.

It does not seem to matter if we create the map from live data or logged data it does the same thing.  If we use the same map on a simulated robot in RViz is shows up and works just fine.  Any suggestions?  How do we keep the map from resizing.  Our current map is 4000 x 4000 and it keeps resizing down to 992 x 992.  We tried to use the 2D Nav pose to position the robot within the map.  It stops jumping around when it gets close to the actual position but it starts jumping again.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269279/imported-map-resizes-and-flickers-in-rviz/) by [mewescott](https://answers.ros.org/users/31649/mewescott/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I read your question text correctly, you appear to be running `gmapping` even though you already have a map. As far as I know, `gmapping` is only involved when *making* a map, not when *using* one you made earlier.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0